# ant fails unknown argument: -buildfile=build.xml

Tags: java, xml, shell, ant

This question might be a basic one but I'm not sure why I'm getting this error:
**Unknown argument: -buildfile=build.xml** when try to run ant in shell script.

I'm using:
**Ant-Version**: 1.9.3
**Os**: Linux
**Java Version**: 1.7.0_65

I'm trying to run ant in a shell script file as follows:
ant -Dfile1=file1 -Dfile2=file2 -buildfile=build.xml -verbose.

Thanks and regards,
Vijay Reddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Running Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html):

```
ant [options] [target [target2 [target3] ...]]

Options:
...
-buildfile <file>      use given buildfile
```

So there should be no `=` between `-buildfile` and `<file` but instead a `space`.

Instead of your:

```
ant -Dfile1=file1 -Dfile2=file2 -buildfile=build.xml -verbose
```

Try:

```
ant -Dfile1=file1 -Dfile2=file2 -buildfile build.xml -verbose
```